# Appending 内 to a company name is read ない or うち?

Tags: readings

For example, if I say マイクロソフト内のパートナーシップは強いです, is the 内 here read as うち or ない?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「内」 in the form:

> 「Proper Noun + 内」

is always read 「ない」.  I just could not think of an exception to this "rule".